# Error using minus in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-struct

```
temp(i,1) = rand(1)*(pb(1,num).pos(i,1) - pw(1,num).pos(i,1));
```

This line gives the following error:

```
Error using ==> minus
Not enough input arguments.
```

The following are the definitions of `pb` and `pw`.

```
pw=struct('fitness',[],'pos',{});
pb=struct('fitness',[],'pos',{});
```

`pos` is a 2 x 1 array.

Answer (score 1):

When tracking down errors like this, I break the problem up into smaller bits. Especially when the logic isn't readily apparent. Not only does it provide a path that can be used to step through your function using the debugger, but it also makes it more readable.

I've taken liberty with the intermediate variable names.

```
thisPb    = pb(1,num);
thisPw    = pw(1,num);
initialPos= pw.pos(i,1);
finalPos  = pb.pos(i,1);
whos initialPos finalPos 
temp(i,1) = rand(1) * (finalPos - initialPos);
```

The line with **whos** will print out the values. Make sure that finalPos and initialPos are both numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can get this error is when `num` is an empty matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
>> s(x).a
```

can return a variable number of outputs, depending on the size of `x`.

If `x = [1,2,3]` for example, it will return three values (as long as `s` has at least three elements).

If `x = []` on the other hand, then `s(x).a` will return no outputs, so the expression

```
>> disp(s(x).a)
```

will give you a `Not enough input arguments` error, which is almost certainly what you're seeing. You should check that `num` is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that all values are really initialised? Try to check this before your codeline.

```
disp(pb(1,num).pos(i,1))
disp(pw(1,num).pos(i,1))
temp(i,1) = rand(1)*(pb(1,num).pos(i,1) - pw(1,num).pos(i,1));
```

Comment: When i write the above mentioned lines above my codeline there are valid values printed on the screen but after the values there is the following error message: Error using ==> disp
Not enough input arguments.

Comment: @user2452541 can you add a `disp(num)` before?